# Disable compositing completely ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity-2d, compositing

I have a clean install of ubuntu 16.04.1. I would like to disable compositing completely. I need to run ABAQUS, and the graphics window becomes transparent if compositing is enabled. Previously I used to run Kubuntu, and if compositing is disabled then ABAQUS GUI will not be transparent.

In 16.04 the ubuntu-2d is not there anymore! I have installed ccsm and tried to disable compositing in the "compiz" section, but that also removed all window decorations.

My goal is to run ABAQUS GUI (not particularly the unity-2D). "abaqus cae -mesa" did not help BTW. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kodanda

Comment: I'm assuming you want the Unity DE?

Comment: Yes, I am using Unity. I do not want to install another DE, unless there is no other option!

Comment: bump! Any help!

Comment: Perhaps using lxde is an option for me. After all it is not going to install tonnes of new libraries. I needed to install `ĺxsession` in addition to `lxde` to get the session changing option available in `lightdm` screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently unity-2D is discontinued in ubuntu 16.04. Thus `lxde` is the next slim option to have a session without compositing enabled.

Answer (score 1):

No need to turn off compositing - on my Ubuntu 16.04.5 I just need to start ABAQUS  with setting `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1` like

```
$ XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 /opt/abaqus/Commands/abaqus cae -mesa -noStartupDialog;
```